# How to force a package removal that dnf wrongly suppose many packages are depending on?

Tags: fedora, package-management, dnf

I am trying to do some clean-up in my package list on a Fedora 37 workstation using `dnf`. I have many packages installed for evaluation purposes and yesterday my upgrade of Fedora 36->37 resulted in the deployment of 10422 packages...

I want to remove

```
cgnslib-common-4.3.0-3.fc37.noarch
cgnslib-4.3.0-3.fc37.x86_64
```

But when I try to proceed with `sudo dnf remove cgnslib` I get:

```
Error: 
Problem: The operation would result in removing the following protected packages: gnome-shell
(try to add '--skip-broken' to skip uninstallable packages)
```

But `cgnslib` is totally unrelated to `gnome-shell` (it is a set of libs and tools for computational fluid dynamics (CFD) analysisdata - `cgns` stands for Computational Fluid Dynamics General Notation System).

How can I force that package removal?

I have already tried a `sudo rpm --rebuilddb` prior to `remove`. If I looks for the package reverse dependencies, I see nothing related to gnome-shell:

````
$ dnf repoquery --whatrequires cgnslib                                       
cgnslib-devel-0:4.3.0-2.fc37.i686
cgnslib-devel-0:4.3.0-2.fc37.x86_64
cgnslib-devel-0:4.3.0-3.fc37.i686
cgnslib-devel-0:4.3.0-3.fc37.x86_64
gmsh-libs-0:4.10.5-2.fc37.i686
gmsh-libs-0:4.10.5-2.fc37.x86_64
gmsh-libs-0:4.10.5-3.fc37.i686
gmsh-libs-0:4.10.5-3.fc37.x86_64
gmsh-mpich-libs-0:4.10.5-2.fc37.i686
gmsh-mpich-libs-0:4.10.5-2.fc37.x86_64
gmsh-mpich-libs-0:4.10.5-3.fc37.i686
gmsh-mpich-libs-0:4.10.5-3.fc37.x86_64
gmsh-openmpi-libs-0:4.10.5-2.fc37.i686
gmsh-openmpi-libs-0:4.10.5-2.fc37.x86_64
gmsh-openmpi-libs-0:4.10.5-3.fc37.i686
gmsh-openmpi-libs-0:4.10.5-3.fc37.x86_64
paraview-0:5.10.1-5.fc37.i686
paraview-0:5.10.1-5.fc37.x86_64
paraview-mpich-0:5.10.1-5.fc37.i686
paraview-mpich-0:5.10.1-5.fc37.x86_64
paraview-openmpi-0:5.10.1-5.fc37.i686
paraview-openmpi-0:5.10.1-5.fc37.x86_64
petsc-0:3.17.4-2.fc37.i686
petsc-0:3.17.4-2.fc37.x86_64
petsc-0:3.17.4-6.fc37.i686
petsc-0:3.17.4-6.fc37.x86_64
petsc-mpich-0:3.17.4-2.fc37.i686
petsc-mpich-0:3.17.4-2.fc37.x86_64
petsc-mpich-0:3.17.4-6.fc37.i686
petsc-mpich-0:3.17.4-6.fc37.x86_64
petsc-openmpi-0:3.17.4-2.fc37.i686
petsc-openmpi-0:3.17.4-2.fc37.x86_64
petsc-openmpi-0:3.17.4-6.fc37.i686
petsc-openmpi-0:3.17.4-6.fc37.x86_64
petsc64-0:3.17.4-2.fc37.x86_64
petsc64-0:3.17.4-6.fc37.x86_64
vtk-0:9.1.0-17.fc37.i686
vtk-0:9.1.0-17.fc37.x86_64
vtk-mpich-0:9.1.0-17.fc37.i686
vtk-mpich-0:9.1.0-17.fc37.x86_64
vtk-openmpi-0:9.1.0-17.fc37.i686
vtk-openmpi-0:9.1.0-17.fc37.x86_64```
````

Comment: I can't reproduce this. What happens if you add `--noautoremove`? (I _hope_ that's not the answer, but I can't think of what else it might be.)

Comment: @mattdm: I just tested that `sudo dnf remove --noautoremove cgnslib` has the same result as the pasted message in my question. :(